# I am trying to understand crontabs

Tags: cron

I set up a crontab to send an email out. All of a sudden the email kept sending like crazy when the time came.

I wanted it to go out at 5am on the 2nd of the month.

This is what it was set to : `* 5 2 * *`

But I'm pretty sure that's not what that does. Can anyone explain what that does instead?

I then went to copy another crontab that was relatively similar and made this :

```
0 5 */2 * *
```

Which I'm pretty sure is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec

```
* 5 2 * *
```

means **every minute** after 5 on the 2nd day of every month. The other spec

```
0 5 */2 * *
```

means at 5:00 on **every second** day of every month, so it isn't what you want either.

You should simply fix the minute spec to something, doesn't have to be zero, but can't be an '*' or you'll get 60 emails between 5 and 6. You can do it like this:

```
0 5 2 * *
```

meaning at 5:00 on the 2nd day of every month or

```
10 5 2 * *
```

meaning at 5:10 on the 2nd day of every month.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `0 5 */2 * *` and `0 5 2 * *`

Comment: `0 5 2 * *` results in execution only once a month, on the 2nd day of each month while `0 5 */2 * *` results in execution around 15 times a month, on the first, third, fifth day and so on of every month.

Comment: That's strange because I have my other crontabs set to that and they fire off specifically once a month.